# Autoscroll and refreshing with Angularjs 1.6

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to make an autoscroll without animations by using this function :

```
 $scope.scrollTo = function(id) {
   $location.hash(id);
   $anchorScroll();
 }
```

The function works correctly, but it's refreshing my page and I don't want it to be refreshed.

By refreshing, I mean that certains GET requests are re-launched not all but some and don't know why. 
And in fact, clicking on a button should scroll to the top and show a div. But without enable the scroll to this button, it is actually showing the div in a good way.
And with the scroll enable to this button, it is actually scrolling to the element but not showing the hidden div.

Comment: What do you mean by 'refreshing'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using [`ngRoute`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute), then you need to set `reloadOnSearch` to false in your route to avoid reloading when the hash changes.

From [the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider):

> `[reloadOnSearch=true]` - `{boolean=}` - reload route when only `$location.search()` or `$location.hash()` changes.
>
> If the option is set to false and url in the browser changes, then `$routeUpdate` event is broadcasted on the root scope.